# memberwiseclone in C# - system.object

Tags: c#, clone

[`MemberwiseClone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will create shallow copy, which will do a bit-by-bit copy of a value type and only copy the references of a reference type. We would need to create a deep copy to have an independent copy of a reference type. This is ok. I get this. 
Now my question is: why does a `System.Object` variable react differently when MemberwiseClone() is called?

Eg:

```
Public class Test
{
    public int x;
    public object obj;

    public Test MyClone()
    {
         return (Test) this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Now access this in my Main method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Test obj1 = new obj1;
     obj1.x = 1;
     obj1.obj = "x";

    Test obj2 = obj1.MyClone();
    obj2.obj = "y" 
}
```

Should this not change the value of `obj1.obj` to y? Since obj is an instance of `System.Object` which is obviously  a reference type. But it does not change - `obj1.obj` gives x and `obj2.obj` gives y. Why is this?

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your edit. Please answer my question, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't change state of field `obj`. You *assign* it.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Test obj1 = new obj1;
     obj1.x = 1;
     obj1.obj = new List<string> {"x"};

    Test obj2 = obj1.MyClone();
    ((List<string>) obj2.obj).Add("y"); //now it contains {x, y} in obj1 and obj2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy. But can you please explain in brief. Also now obj is no longer reference type? with List<string> as string is value type?

Comment: @Zodiac, `List<>` is reference type regardless of if it contains a value type list

Comment: @Zodiac, there's a good explanation in Jon Skeet's article: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html

Comment: @2kay, I think i get it, when i explicitly convert obj to list<string> i have made it to refrence type and now both obj1.obj and ob2.obj will point to same object. But why does this not happen when we assign it directly. when i doe obj1.obj = "X" does it treat obj as value type here? It looks like it does

Comment: Thanks @Furqan, for clearing that. Just put some light on my question to 2kay if you can. thanks buddy

Comment: @Zodiac, since string is a special object type that is `immutable` cannot be changed once assigned, so when you declare strings with literals e.g. "X" it is assigned on Stack and  not on heap(unlike other objects),not eligible for Garbage collection.  But when you assign string as `new string(new char[]{'H', 'e', 'l','l','o'})` , it is declared on heap and is eligible for garbage collection. One more thing is that when multiple strings are assigned a literal value "X", the CLR pools the value "X" and reuse it rather than assigning multiple "X" on stack. There is more to it,but no space left.

Comment: @Furqan - Thanks for explanation buddy. Just one last question when i say object x = "a", it means i have just defined a string?

Answer (score 1):

1. your code contains 3 syntax errors (this cannot run)
2. considering your code:

   public static void Main()
   {
   Test obj1 = new obj1;
   obj1.x = 1;
   obj1.obj = "x";

   ```
    Test obj2 = obj1.MyClone();
    obj2.obj = "y"
   ```

   }

your wrong thinking lies here:

```
obj2.obj = "y"
```

this does not change the value of obj, it assings a different string object which is not related to the non-cloned instance.

this is because every string is an immutable object. a different string results in a different object on the heap.

But if you *actually* manage to change the string content itself, then you get the expected effect.

using unsafe mode you can prove it this way:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test obj1 = new Test();
        obj1.x = 1;
        obj1.obj = "abc";

        Test obj2 = obj1.MyClone();

        var obj1Str = obj1.obj as string;

        ReverseString(obj1Str);

        var obj2Str = obj2.obj as string;

        Debug.Print(obj2Str); // "cba"
    }

    static unsafe void ReverseString(string str)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = str.Length - 1;

        fixed (char* fstr = str)
            while (i < j)
            {
                char temp = fstr[j];

                fstr[j--] = fstr[i];
                fstr[i++] = temp;
            }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int x;
    public object obj;

    public Test MyClone()
    {
        return (Test)MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```